# Correct Specular-Term of the Cook-Torrance- Torrance-Sparrow-Model

Tags: math, graphics, rendering, physics

For a while I have been doing some research on the Topic of PBR and one reflection-models mentioned over and over is the Cook-Torrance-/ Torrance-Sparrow-model and it seems that in any mention or explanation of this model another form of the specular term is used. The versions I have found are:

(1): F*D*H / pi*(N dot V*(N dot L)

(2): F*D*H / (N dot V)*(N dot L)

(3): F*D*H / 4*(N dot V)*(N dot L)

Which one is when correct? In *PBR: From Theory to Implementation* is a conclusive derivation of the first one, but in their original paper Cook and Torrance use the third one without any detailed explanation.

I hope you can help me.

I would also be happy if someone explained to me how to write mathematical formulas in a Stack Overflow post.